# How to build Unreal C++ project on KDevelop on LInux?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, kdevelop

I have been unsuccessfully trying to compile a c++/blueprint project using Plugins like [SocketIO-for-UE](https://github.com/getnamo/socketio-client-ue4) or [VA-REST](https://github.com/ufna/VaRest). And now that i realize any C++ fails. creating C++ in Source folder also leads to the same error.
Cannot even start a new C++ Project. It Fails to compile and ask me to build through an IDE.

Starts with:

[image: error1]

"Rebuild Now" gives:

[image]

I tried few approaches but nothing seems to work.

```
GenerateProjectFiles.sh /path/to/.uproject
```

the above generated a Makefile in the project root, Having that imported to Kdevelop, build seems to work fine but doesn't seem to compile or do any thing with the Plugins folder.

[image: Kdevelop]

Any help would be much appreciated and will generate lot of good karma for you.

I'm Using:
UE4 4.26.1 (Crashes regularly) & 4.26.2

Ubuntu 20

Kdevelop 5.5

Comment: So, you're saying all of Kdevelop is broken, so you can't compile any C++ project with it? Try reinstalling or updating it to a more recent version.

Comment: They are all latest versions Kdevelop 5.5 and tried UE4.26.1 & UE4.26.2. tested with both. I dont think Kdevelop is broken. Kdevelop doesn't  compile Plugins. and UE4 doesn't compile c++. Feels like I'm in a gridlock. seems like only option is abandon project.

Comment: Why should UE compile C++? Why not compile from the CLI outside of the IDE? Does that work?

Comment: that would be cool but I haven't come across the possibility. If you can shed some light on how, i would be really grateful.

Comment: UE4 Linux documentation is really sparse on such matters, unfortunately. or I'm a terrible searcher.

Comment: The recommended editor for UE is VS-Code. I answered a similar question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233814/how-to-buildrun-unreal-c-project-on-linux

Comment: Crashes are probably related to your nvidia driver. I had to fix mine to `450`. Later version crashed UE a lot.

Comment: @fjardon I tried your answer. still the same messages. Any other ideas? I started off with VSCode. That's my preferred IDE as well. I thought unreal was more lenient with Kdeveloper. QtCreator doesnt work either.